# Writing an array with a for loop doesn't work

Tags: contract-debugging, truffle-contract

I am trying to fill an array of cards in a deck with values from 0 to 51 using an array. It doesn't seem to work and I always end up with an empty array. Is this an issue with gas even though I experimented with fairly big values for gas limit. Here is my code:

```
contract Blackjack {

   uint[52] public deck;

   function Blackjack() public {

       for (uint i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
            deck[i] = i;
       }
    }
}
```

Edit: I just realized that you need to give a parameter when calling the free getter for deck in remix. I was expecting it would return the whole array so this isn't really an issue. Thanks to everyone who helped out and sorry to have wasted your time.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: No error just no values when I try to access the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contract works as is, warnings and all. You can see that in Remix.

[image]

In case it helps on the client side, you would call the "free" getter function you receive from `public`. It looks similar to Lauri's idea:

```
function getit(uint row) public view returns (uint) {
    return deck[row];
}
```

If you don't receive the values (one at a time) focus on the client.

Also, you may be surprised to receive a strange array from Web3 (maybe this is "it"). It will be in BigNumber format. https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#a-note-on-big-numbers-in-web3js

BigNumbers looks like wonky arrays. Take your `response` and `response.toString(10)` to read a human-readable number.

Also, it's async.

If you're using truffle

```
instance.deck().then(function(response) { // console.log(response.toString(10)); });
```

If not truffle, I believe

```
instance.deck(function(error, response) { // console.log(response.toString(10)); });
```

I am a little sketchy on contract access methods when not using truffle, so perhaps a kind soul will chime in a correct any obvious errors.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Turns out I wasn't calling the free getter appropriately. I was expecting it to return the whole array and instead it was expecting an index for the value of the array so it's sorted, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What Solidity and compiler versions are you using?

If you have `pragma solidity ^0.4.22;` at the top of your file, try changing the constructor to the new format:

```
function Blackjack() public {
```

should become

```
constructor() public {
```

(Note: you don't need to write `function` when declaring `constructor`)

Comment: I'm using 0.4.2 but the issue was me not understanding how array getters work. Don't want to go off-topic but is there some major advantages to using 0.4.22 as the tutorials I watched used 0.4.2 and I just stayed with it?

Comment: Yes, Solidity is very new, and it's a rapidly evolving. Solidity 0.4.2 is about a year and a half old - I can only imagine what improvements have happened since then. If the tutorials you're using are using anything earlier than 0.4.16 I wouldn't even bother. You should find quality material from at least 0.4.18 though.

The reason I mentioned the version thing was because I didn't think your constructor was being called, but I don't think you should be learning 0.4.2 regardless

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a gas issue unless you excplicitly get gas errors when deploying. How are you checking the actual values in the array? You don't have a function for it.

Try this (in Remix for example):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;

contract Blackjack {

   uint[52] public deck;

   constructor() public {

       for (uint i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
            deck[i] = i;
       }
    }

    function getit() public view returns (uint) {
        return deck[5];
    }
}
```

Now you can create the contract and after that call the `getit` function to retrieve a value from the array. It works here at least.

Comment: I'm using remix and I was just calling the free getter that I get "deck". It would always return a blank array

Comment: I have found out what the problem is, edited the question.. I was just being stupid. Thanks for the suggestions though!